# What is the difference between ''1 C atom and 1 mole of C atoms?''

Tags: physical-chemistry, stoichiometry, atoms, molecules

1. Does 1 C atom mean 1 single C atom out of Avogadro's number of C atoms = 1 single C atom out of 6.023 X 10^23 numbers of C atoms?
2. Does 1 mole of C atoms mean Avogadro's number of C atoms = 6.023 X 10^23 numbers of C atoms?

I am confused. Could you clarify it, please?

Comment: Clarify what? 2) is exactly what the definition says and no idea what 1) is supposed to be, 1 atom is one atom, that's it.

Comment: What is the difference between 1 grain of sand and 1 tonne of grains of sand? Does the former mean 1 grain of sand out of 10^9 numbers of grains of sand?

Answer (score 10):

What is the difference between one egg and one dozen eggs?  A dozen is simply a certain count, in this case 12, that is rendered as one unit for our convenience.  Avogadro's number s just the same thing as a dozen, except we made the unit count larger than 12 in order to match it up with our conventionally used units.

Your assumptions about a "mole" are thus correct.

Comment: This sounds more like a badly-worded notation question to me.

Answer (score 3):

1 C atom is just one particle of the unique element Carbon. There is virtually no way to isolate or work with a single atom of anything.

1 mole of C is a quantity, like a dozen or a gross. We use dozens for food sale, like eggs, and a gross for small items like pencils. The power of the quantity a 'mole' comes from the mass of a mole in grams. When you have 6.02 x 10^23 particles, you have the formula mass in grams.

1 dozen eggs will weigh differently than 1 dozen bicycles.

Likewise, i mole of any substance will have a mass equal to the species atomic mass, or formula mass.

So, 1 mole of Carbon will have a mass of about 12.01 g (the number written will depend on the periodic table). 1 Mole of water will have a mass of 18 g (approx)

This is why the mole is such a useful quantity.